# Filtro Ajax no wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, filtro, custom-post-types

Ola, gostaria de saber se alguém já fez alguma funcionalidade igual a desse site, http://www.todeschinisa.com.br/pt/onde-encontrar filtrando os post usando um formulario e ajax para nao precisar dar o reload na pagina.

Estou com a seguinte situação, criei um custom post type revendas, onde ativei `'taxonomies'  => array( 'category' )`, criei a categoria Brasil com os filhos como estados, e dentro de cada estado as cidades.

Mas nao estou conseguindo criar um formulario nem filtrar os post

```
[Brasil] [Estado] [Cidade] [Filtrar]
```

seria algo assim.

Comment: Crie as funções no functions.php e acesse usando ajax. Tipo assim: http://www.kenner.com.br/action-gel-explore/

Comment: show, bem isso, teria algum tutorial com o passo a passo para me basear?

Comment: Para adiantar, dá uma olhada nesse artigo que tem a função para incluir no functions.php e o código javascript para acessar a função que mais tarde quando eu chegar em casa monto uma resposta completa que facilitará o entendimento. https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Blz, vou ler o artigo. provavelmente amanhã vou retomar o desenvolvimento do projeto

Comment: Andre, você me deu uma baita luz, me diga uma coisa, sou bem novo na area, você recomenda fazer o filtro do pais estado cidade usando categoria, um um custom field com ACF crio os campos, Pais, estado e cidade

Comment: Patrick, nesse aí eu implementei com tabela nova no mysql porque advém de uma planilha enviada para a carga.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por segurança, para que você não tenha requisições para vários arquivos php, aconselho você a criar as funções no functions.php e acessar as funções usando ajax.

Para esta implementação usei apenas uma tabela, mas você poderia montar usando o formato de armazenamento wordpress, depende do tempo e prazo. :)

No **functions.php**, criamos as funções e as ações para permitir a passar parâmetros:

```
// Ação de callback do Ajax
function get_cidade_from_uf() {
  global $wpdb;
  $query = " SELECT  distinct m.TXT_CIDADE FROM tb_lojas m
             WHERE m.COD_UF = '".$_GET['COD_UF']."' ORDER BY TXT_CIDADE ASC ";
  $cidades = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);    
  die(json_encode($cidades));
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_cidade_from_uf', 'get_cidade_from_uf' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_cidade_from_uf', 'get_cidade_from_uf' );

// Ação de callback do Ajax
function get_bairro_from_cidade_uf() {
  global $wpdb;
  $query = " SELECT  distinct m.TXT_BAIRRO FROM tb_lojas m
             WHERE m.COD_UF = '".$_GET['COD_UF']."' 
               AND m.TXT_CIDADE = '".$_GET['TXT_CIDADE']."'
             ORDER BY TXT_BAIRRO ASC ";
  $bairros = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);
  die(json_encode($bairros));   
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_bairro_from_cidade_uf', 'get_bairro_from_cidade_uf' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_bairro_from_cidade_uf', 'get_bairro_from_cidade_uf' );

// Ação de callback do Ajax
function get_procurar_loja() {
  global $wpdb;
  $uf = $_GET['COD_UF'];
  $cidade = $_GET['TXT_CIDADE'];
  $bairro = $_GET['TXT_BAIRRO'];
  $query = " SELECT l.TXT_LOJA, l.TXT_ENDERECO, l.TXT_BAIRRO, l.TXT_CIDADE, l.COD_UF FROM tb_lojas l WHERE l.COD_UF = '".$uf."' ";
  if ( (isset( $cidade)) ) {
     if ( ($cidade !='') && ($cidade != 'undefined') && ($cidade != 'CIDADE') && ($cidade != 'SELECIONE UMA CIDADE') ){
       $query .= " AND l.TXT_CIDADE = '".$cidade."' ";
     }
  }
  if ( (isset( $bairro)) ) {
     if ( ($bairro !='') && ($bairro != 'undefined') && ($bairro != 'BAIRRO') && ($bairro!= 'SELECIONE UM BAIRRO') ){
         $query .= " AND l.TXT_BAIRRO = '".$bairro."' ";
     }
  }
  $query .= "   ORDER BY l.TXT_LOJA ASC ";    
  $lojas = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);
  die(json_encode($lojas)); 
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_procurar_loja', 'get_procurar_loja' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_procurar_loja', 'get_procurar_loja' );
```

No **javascript** você coloca os eventos e os tratamentos:

```
 $("#btnProcurar").click(function() {
    var inputUF = $("#txtUF").val();    
    var inputCidade = $("#txtCIDADE").val();
    var inputBairro = $("#txtBAIRRO").val();    
    $.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'get',
        data: {
            'action': 'get_procurar_loja',
            'COD_UF': inputUF,
            'TXT_CIDADE': inputCidade,
            'TXT_BAIRRO': inputBairro
        },
        success: function( data ){           
            var data = JSON.parse(data);            
            var out = '<ul>';
            jQuery.each(data, function(index, item) {
                var loja = item.TXT_LOJA.trim();
                 out += "<li oncopy='javascript:textocopiado(\"" + loja + "\");'><b><span style='color:orangered;font-family:Trade Gothic LT Std Bold Sinistra;'>"+item.TXT_LOJA+"</span></b><br><span style='color:#f8f8ff;font-family:Trade Gothic LT Std Bold Condensed;'>"+item.TXT_ENDERECO+"<br>"+item.TXT_BAIRRO+" - "+item.TXT_CIDADE+" - " + item.COD_UF + "<br></li>";            
              });
            out += '</ul>';
            $('#hotsite-lojas').html(out);                      
            $('#hotsite-lojas').show();
        }
    });
  });
  $("#txtUF").change(function() {
    var inputUf = $("#txtUF").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'get',
        data: {
            'action': 'get_cidade_from_uf',
            'COD_UF': inputUf
        },
        success: function( data ){          
            var data = JSON.parse(data);
            var selectCidade = document.getElementById("txtCIDADE");            
            selectCidade.innerText = null;
            var selecione = document.createElement("option");
            selecione.text = '  SELECIONE UMA CIDADE';
            selectCidade.add(selecione);
            jQuery.each(data, function(index, item) {               
              var option = document.createElement("option");              
              option.text = '  ' + item.TXT_CIDADE;
              if (option.text != 'undefined') {
                selectCidade.add(option);
              }
            });                     
        }
    });
  });
  $("#txtCIDADE").change(function() {
    var inputUF = $("#txtUF").val();
    var inputCidade = $("#txtCIDADE").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'get',
        data: {
            'action': 'get_bairro_from_cidade_uf',
            'COD_UF': inputUF,
            'TXT_CIDADE': inputCidade
        },
        success: function( data ){          
            var data = JSON.parse(data);
            var selectBairro = document.getElementById("txtBAIRRO");            
            selectBairro.innerText = null;
            var selecione = document.createElement("option");
            selecione.text = '  SELECIONE UM BAIRRO';
            selectBairro.add(selecione);
            jQuery.each(data, function(index, item) {               
              var option = document.createElement("option");
              option.text = '  ' + item.TXT_BAIRRO;
              if (option.text != 'undefined') {
                selectBairro.add(option);
              }
            });         
        }
    });
  });
```

Espero que ajude.

Com Custom Type ficaria bem melhor, mas aí fica como desafio... e não esquece de compartilhar.

Grande abraço

Comment: show, irei tentara fazer aqui assim que tiver o resultado funcionando compartilho para a galera

Comment: Andre, voce quem desenvolve a mais tempo que eu pode me responder essa, saberia como criar uma forma dinamica para inserir as informacoes na tabela, por exemplo criar um custom post type e a apartir dele alguma tabela para posteriormente puxar essas informacoes. Nao quero perder o dinamismo do wordpress, toda vez que precisar adicionar uma revenda precisar editar a tabela

Comment: assim que parar um minuto (ou mais, rs) vou escrever com custom post types..

Comment: fiz de outra maneira, vou postar assim que tiver um tempo, mas fiz com busca, a pessoa digita a localizacao ele diz se tem ou nao. Mas se puder ajudar a turma com custom post nao achei nenhum material explicando como fazer